# Using proptypes on a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-proptypes

i'm folowing an egghead react tutorial where the tutor tried to implement proptypes on a function component without using the prop-types api, and this is the way how he did it:

```
                    function SayHello(props){
                        return (
                            <div>
                                Hello {props.firstName} {props.lastName} !
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                    SayHello.propTypes = {
                        firstName(props, propName, componentName) {
                            if (typeof props[propName] !== 'string') {
                                return new Error(`Hey, you should pass a string for ${propName} in ${componentName} but you passed a ${typeof props[propName]}`)
                            }

                      }
                    }
```

this might be a dumb question but i really can't understand how this bit of code works, can someone please explain it to me, how `firstName(props, propName, componentName)` is called without being invokated and
how it comes that the `componentName` returns `SayHello` ?
is it a default property in every component ?

Comment: It is being invoked, by the react.js code

Answer (score 0):

The actual prop-type checkers (e.f. `array`, `bool`, etc) from react 'prop-types' library return the function of the following signature

```
function validate(props, propName, componentName, location, propFullName, secret)
```

So react library simply calls this functions with the arguments regarding the current component being validated.

If you can write your own function like the tutor did, it should work the same